# How to make non-editable combo box in dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to make non-editable combo box in following code. I am using ESRI ArcGIS Java Script API 3.2. Dojo/dijit is tightly integrated in this API.

What I tried :

1.I changed the read only value but after making true my combo box is grayed out and not active.

2.I have checked the dojo/digit API reference and tried using by "disabled" but its disabling combo box  and not able select any values.

3.Researching on Google too.

Software's : ArcGIS Java Script API 3.2 & Dojo version 1.6

so any help will be great !!!

thanks in advance : )

Complete code at [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5quYE/)

Code :

```
             dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
             region="top"
             style="height:25px;">
        <select id="mySelect" 
             dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox"
             style="width:250px;font-size:18px;"
             autoComplete="true",
             forceValidOption="false",
             readOnly = "false",
             value="Select"
             fetchProperties="{sort:[{attribute:'name', descending:false}]}" 
             onchange="applyLayerDef(this)">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [dijit/form/FilteringSelect](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply I have seen the link and the examples. Actually I want to disable the type option in combo box (should be read only)